# How much time a image classification algo can take?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, anaconda

I have written below code for recognizing images.

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())
# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.2,
zoom_range = 0.2,
horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('E:\\ML_R&D\\training_set\\cats1',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('E:\\ML_R&D\\test_set\\cats1',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
steps_per_epoch = 8000,
epochs = 25,
validation_data = test_set,
validation_steps = 2000)
# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('E:\\ML_R&D\\cat.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
```

when i run this code it is running successfully without any error, but after waiting for hours(2) no result displayed. It just displays below.

Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Epoch 1/25

Comment: The generator found 0 images and 0 classes, that's a problem.

Comment: I have around 200 images at the specified location, the location and images are accessible .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the directory structure you are giving.

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('E:\\ML_R&D\\training_set\\cats1',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
```

Here the path `E:\\ML_R&D\\training_set\\cats1` must contain subfolders (representing each class) where inside each subfolder you are having images belonging to that particular class.

For example

`/home/tlokeshkumar/Documents/image_data` is the place where my dataset is present.

```
image_data
    class_1
        class_1_1.jpg
        class_1_2.jpg
        ...
    class_2
        class_2_1.jpg
        class_2_2.jpg
        class_2_3.jpg
        ...
    class_3
    class_4
    ...
```

If this structure is followed, you must enter the path of the master folder (`image_data`) must be given.

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('home/tlokeshkumar/Documents/image_data',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
```

For [Fast image classification](https://github.com/tlokeshkumar/Fast-image-classification) you can have a look into my repository where I have used keras to write an image classifier which uses bottlenecks to train it much faster than normal training procedure.